# How to measure communication between nodes in Spark Standalone Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I use Spark Standalone Cluster and I want to know how much information nodes send to each other. How can I measure it?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

Answer (score 1):

you can you monitoring tools like ganglia and nagios for that. For my personal opinion i go for ganglia.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use full monitoring system like zabbix to gather information from all your nodes.

Also if you are interesting in fact of sending data between nodes you may have a look into driver's UI (usually at 4040 port). Check locality level of each task and if you will find "ANY" it means possible data transfer between worker nodes.